# Jquery chat windows with unique id's

Tags: jquery

I have some problems with my chat code. How can I make it so that each unique chat window (that opens depending on which item id clicked), it will send a message. I got it to work for the first chat window as it's the general div.

I tried putting "#chat_text_"+id but that didn't work as it said id was undefined even though I have it defined at the upper part of the code.

And the other problem is, after the chat windows open side by side, once closed, the next time I open them they start from the middle of the screen and behave weird until I refresh.. I tried reseting 'num' to 0 but that didn't help. I want to make it move to the right side of screen until it hits another chat window. If there is not chat window (or one was just closed) -> slide to the right

the div it appends to:

```
<div id="chats"> 
        <div class="chat_window"> 

        </div> 
    </div>
```

jquery:

```
 <script> 
            var num = 0; 
            function chatWith(id, username, cover, title){ 
                $("#chats").append('<div class="chat_window" id="chat_'+id+'"><div class="chat_top"><span class="chat_username">'+username+'</span><span class="chat_x"><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="minChat('+id+')">-</a> <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="closeChat('+id+')">X</a> </span><br> <div class="chat_cover"><img src="'+cover+'" alt=" " style="width:15px;height:15px"> '+title+'</div> </div> <div class="chat_content"></div> <form method="post" name="chat" action=""> <textarea class="chat_text" maxlength="200" name="chat_text" id="chat_text_'+id+'" placeholder="Start typing..."></textarea> </form> </div></dv>'); 
                $("#chat_"+id).slideToggle("up");  
                var move_px = num*225; 
                $('#chat_'+id).animate({ right: "+="+move_px}, 200, function() { }); 
                    num+=1;             
            } 
            function minChat(id){    
                $("#chat_"+id).animate({'margin-bottom':'-18em'});  
            } 
            function closeChat(id){ 
                $("#chat_"+id).slideToggle("down"); 
            } 

            //send messages
            var user_id = '<?php if(logged_in()==true){echo $session_user_id;}?>';
            var auto_refresh = setInterval(function () {
                var b = $("#chat_"+user_id+":last").attr("id");     
                $.getJSON("chat.php?q="+user_id,function(data){
                    $.each(data.posts, function(i,data) {               
                        if(b != data.id)  { 
                            var div_data="<span id='"+data.id+"'>"+data.user_id+": "+data.msg+"</span>";                        
                            $(div_data).appendTo("#chat_"+user_id);
                        }
                    });
                });
            }, 2000);   
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $(document).keypress(function(e) {
                    if(e.which == 13) {
                        var boxval = $(".chat_text").val();                 
                        var user_id = '<?php if(logged_in()==true){echo $session_user_id;}?>';
                        var dataString = 'user_id='+ user_id + '&msg=' + boxval;

                        if(boxval.length > 0) { 
                            $.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                url: "chat.php",
                                data: dataString,
                                cache: false,
                                success: function(html){                     
                                    $(".chat_content").append(html);
                                    $(".chat_text").val('');
                                    $(".chat_text").focus();
                                    $(".chat_content").animate({scrollTop: $(".chat_text").offset().top}, 500);
                                }
                            });             
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried looking in the console? It is spitting out tonnes of errors.

Comment: I only got one waring: "event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead." which I wasn't sure how to fix

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using? I am getting `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #chat_<?php if(logged_in()==true){echo $session_user_id;}?>:last jquery-2.1.0.js:1429
Sizzle.error jquery-2.1.0.js:1429
tokenize jquery-2.1.0.js:2043
select jquery-2.1.0.js:2431
Sizzle jquery-2.1.0.js:838
jQuery.fn.extend.find jquery-2.1.0.js:2642
jQuery.fn.init jquery-2.1.0.js:2750
jQuery jquery-2.1.0.js:78
(anonymous function)`

Comment: 1.10.2 and i am not getting these errors you posted :/

Comment: Oh I know why, I was using JSFiddle, which doesn't allow you to input PHP. Stupid mistake, my bad.

Comment: ok. can someone help me with this?